# How do you make the borders of a cell the same as others?

Tags: excel

In excel, how do you change the border of a cell to be the same of other cells without having to change the content inside of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no other formats, select the cell that has the border, click "Format Painter" and then click the cell you want to take on the same border style.